# Unclosed client session warning of unknown origin

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using a third-party API client library that is based on aiohttp. The library doesn't implement it's clients as context managers, but that should be no problem as long as I always close the `aiohttp.ClientSession` manually (right?).

The problem is that even after carefully doing this I still get the `Unclosed client session` warning without any information from where it is coming from. I'm capturing the warnings traceback with `pytest -W error::ResourceWarning`, but the result is simply

```
.Exception ignored in: <bound method ClientSession.__del__ of <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x10fc15ba8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<PROJECT>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 211, in __del__
    **kwargs)
ResourceWarning: Unclosed client session <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x10fc15ba8>
```

i.e. a traceback with a single frame.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and how I can get more information about that warning?

Answer (score 5):

Run your code in debug mode.

Set `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1` environment variable to see the extended information.

In particular, aiohttp logs a traceback to the line that was used to creating unclosed `ClientSession` object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error, it is just a warning. It comes from a `__del__` function in `ClientSession` ([github](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/8e92c4c7c305f914c17f41539da20822ea7baddf/aiohttp/client.py#L295)). It means that the client got an `WSMsgType.CLOSE` message from the server.

If you are using websockets and the function `ws_connect` ([aiohttp docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html)) It is handled automatically by the argument `autoclose=True`. You could set it to false and see what will happen. You could simply turn off the Internet and then turn it on and see a new response in the console with `WSMsgType.CLOSE` message.